# Is there any way to send a string from Elixir to PHP securely?(no SSL)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to send a string from Elixir/Phoenix(Sever) to PHP(client) securely through URL query string(like: ?secure_string=xxxxx). The environments have no SSL,  but they can share a private key in advance. So I thought I can convey the string securely with encrypting, such as AES.

Since PHP has openssl_decrypt(), it can decrypt the string like following. Elixir(or Erlang?) could call openssl_encrypt, other than System.cmd("/usr/bin/openssl")? Is there any other(better) ways?

```
$key = 'private_key_string_shared_both';
$algorithm = 'AES-128-ECB'
$decrypt = openssl_decrypt($encrypt_string, $algorithm, $key);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:crypto` application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html). It is an Erlang application capable for encrypting and decrypting using different ciphers.

```
:crypto.block_decrypt(:aes_ecb, key, data)
```

Both key and data need to have number of bytes divisible by 16. They can be either binaries `"like this"` or iolists `'like this'`. Working example would be:

```
iex(1)> key = List.duplicate(100, 16)
'dddddddddddddddd'
iex(2)> string = List.duplicate(101, 16)
'eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee'
:crypto.block_encrypt(:aes_ecb, key, string)
<<6, 190, 103, 115, 142, 170, 75, 103, 128, 93, 168, 196, 108, 253, 41, 27>>
```

[Example on how to do padding of binaries in Erlang](https://github.com/spawngrid/cowboy_session/blob/master/src/cowboy_session_secure.erl#L63)

Comment: Did I miss something? It doesn't match...

`iex(1)> :crypto.block_encrypt(:aes_ebc, "key", "string")`
`** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :crypto.block_encrypt/3`
`(crypto) crypto.erl:375: :crypto.block_encrypt(:aes_ebc, 'key', "str")`

Comment: There might be other issues, but you have a typo: it's `:aes_ecb ` not `:aes_ebc `

Comment: @pjam Yes, that is one thing, but even after fixing the typo, there will another error `ArgumentError`, because both key and string need to have size divisible by 16. I updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: @tkowal It worked!. I fail to decode the bitstring in PHP, though. Anyway, thank you.